# Unable to authenticate an user in order to change their password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I want to authenticate an user via devise, then visit their account page and change their password.

```
describe Users::UsersController do
  describe "abc" do

    it "abc" do
      user = FactoryGirl.create :user
      sign_in :user, user
      visit edit_user_registration_path

      save_and_open_page # -- user isn't authenticated yet!

      fill_in # .......
    end

  end
```

However, this test works well

```
it "should sign in" do
  user = FactoryGirl.create :user
  sign_in :user, user
  subject.current_user.should_not be_nil
end
```

Comment: can you add your console log...to see why it is failing

Comment: @RahulSingh, how to log it?

Comment: @RahulSingh, there is no exception, the test goes on working well after "sign_in".

Comment: you would be running it with "$ rspec spec" on terminal, is it failing somewhere...?  if yes then add your terminal output...so that we can see why it is failing.

Comment: @RahulSingh, there is no exception before `fill_in`. at fill_in it says the element is not found which makes sense because it isn't authenticated.

Comment: i have done devise authentication using rspec but little different way...let me add it as an answer...

Answer (score 0):

what i have done is- created a file inside spec/support/utilities.rb
and my utilities.rb have this

```
def sign_in(user)
  visit new_user_session_path
  fill_in "Email",    with: user.email
  fill_in "Password", with: user.password
  click_button "Sign in" 
end
```

after in spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb (which was created by me) and did devise authentication this way

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'UserPages' do

  subject { page }

  describe "allow registered user to sign in successfully" do
       before do
          user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
          sign_in user
        end
       it { should have_link("Logout") }
       it { should_not have_link("Login") }
  end

  describe "edit" do
        before do
           @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)    
           sign_in @user
           visit edit_user_registration_path    
        end

        describe "with valid information" do
           let!(:new_name)  { "New Name" }
           let!(:new_password) { "newpassword" }

           before do
             fill_in "Name",                        with: new_name
             fill_in "Email",                       with: @user.email
             fill_in "user[password]",              with: new_password
             fill_in "user[password_confirmation]",     with: new_password
             click_button "Update"
           end
           specify { @user.reload.name.should  == new_name }
        end
   end
end
```

and my spec/factories.rb have this

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:username)  { |n| "Person_#{n}" }
    sequence(:name)  { |n| "Person #{n}" }
    sequence(:email) { |n| "person_#{n}@example.com"} 
    password "foobar123"
    password_confirmation "foobar123"
  end
end
```

Comment: bcoz sign_in m/d requires only one params and it should be user not :user,